# Cómo puedo coger el valor de un campo desde django models

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.7

Tengo esta tabla:

```
    class producto(models.Model):
        modelo= models.CharField(_('modelo'), max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
        fecha_hasta = models.DateField(_('To'), blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)
        secuencia = models.IntegerField(_('Secuencia), blank=False, null=False)
        fecha_salida = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  @classmethod
    def contador(cls, secuencia: Union[int, None]) -> Tuple[int, int]:

        if None in (secuencia):
            #
            if "prueba" in clase.nombre:
                secuencia = 9000
```

Esto está mal, me sale este error "argument of type 'DeferredAttribute' is not iterable"

Comment: Esa función aplicala en una vista.

Comment: en condiciones normales haría eso, pero la función de arriba la estoy modificando y es algo que funciona que han hecho mis compañeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final pude hacerlo desde el models como quería y lo hice así:

```
    @classmethod
    def contador(cls) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        ultimo = clase.objects.filter(nombre="prueba.xml").order_by('-secuencia').first() #filtro por el fichero de prueba
        if ultimo:
            sequence = ultimo.sequence + 1 #Añado la secuencia solo si se ha añadido el fichero de prueba
        else:
            sequence = 1
        return (sequence)
```

Comment: Si es la respuesta que buscabas y tú mismo te has respondido, acepta tu respuesta para cerrar la pregunta e intenta explicar lo que hace el código por si le puede servir a otra gente con el msmo problema. Un saludo